# How to switch between two React component into a single file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

using MVC .NET, I have view A and B. The problem is I don't know how to render the right component to the right View because it is using the same file.

For instance, into this jsx file, I have

```
export class A extends React.Component {}

export class B extends React.Component {}

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  if ... return A else return B
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (true) {
      return <A />
    } else {
      return <B />
    }
  }
}
```

Let's elaborate this example:

When you use Main component, you'll be using like this:

```
<Main someOption={true} />
```

Now, inside the Main class, you may check:

```
if(this.props.someOption) // replaced to true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This approach:**

```
 /** A class holding A component **/
    export class A extends React.Component {}

    /** B class holding B componennt **/
    export class B extends React.Component {}

    /** Main Class **/
    export default class Main extends React.Component {
        render(){

           let aComponent = true; //it will depends on which component you want to render
           let componentToRender = <A />;
           if(!aComponent){
             componentToRender = <B />;
           } 
           return(
             <div>{componentToRender}</div>
           )
        }
    }
```

Use `Main` component like:

```
<Main />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the code below:

```
/** ViewA Component **/
export class ViewA extends React.Component {}

/** ViewB componennt **/
export class ViewB extends React.Component {}

/** View main class **/
export default class ViewMain extends React.Component {
    render(){
       let aComponent = true; //a threshold should be changed.
       return aComponent?<ViewA/>:<ViewB/>;
    }
}
```